# .htaccess help - 301 redirect URL's with special characters

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

I'm having trouble setting up the following 301 redirects.

I'm trying to redirect:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3
```

to the home page:

```
https://www.example.com/
```

This is what I tried but doesn't work.

```
Redirect 301 "/blog/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js\?ver\=1\.11\.3" "/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QueryString is not part of match in Redirect directive, you need to match against %{THE_REQUEST} using mod-rewrite,try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery\.js\?ver=1\.11\.3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R]
```

You can remove the **?** from the target path if you want to forword the query strings to homepage.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on this page https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

> Unfortunately, neither `Redirect` nor `RedirectMatch` allow you to specify a query string for the redirect source.

So you have to switch to using `mod_rewrite`, i.e. use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/blog/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery\.js$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ver=1\.11\.3$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```